# onClick is not executing function

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a hyperlink, styled to look like a button, and set it do `onClick="function()"`, but when I click it it won't execute. I have my JS in a separate file than the HTML file if that is of any use.

How I linked it 
`<script src="script.js"></script>`

The Hyperlink

```
<ul id='nav'>
    <li> 
         <a onClick="playerNum()">Play</a> 
    </li> 
    <li> 
         <span style='float: right;'> 
         <a onClick="rules()">Rules</a></span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

My JavaScript

```
var playerNum = function () {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 
         "<h2 style='font-family: calibri'> Choose single or multiplayer </h2>" +
         "<br >" +
         "<ul id='nav'>" +
         "   <li> <a onClick='singlePlay()'> Singleplayer </a> </li>" +
         "   <li> <a onClick='multiPlay()'> Multiplayer </a> </li>" +
         "</ul> "
};
```

Comment: Do your javascript functions singlePlay() or multiPlay() move at all? If they do, you will need to re-initialize them. Javascript that is loaded by (or moved by) javascript is generally not executable.

Comment: I broke your html string apart so people don't have to scroll endlessly

Comment: Did you wrap your js code in a loading function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me.  Do you have an element with `id="log"`?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7b83omw/1/

HTML:

```
<ul id='nav'>
    <li> 
         <a onclick="playerNum()">Play</a> 
    </li> 
    <li> 
         <span style='float: right;'> 
         <a onclick="rules()">Rules</a></span> 
    </li>
</ul>
<div id='log'></div>
```

javascript:

```
var playerNum = function () {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 
         "<h2 style='font-family: calibri'> Choose single or multiplayer </h2>" +
         "<br >" +
         "<ul id='nav'>" +
         "   <li> <a onClick='singlePlay()'> Singleplayer </a> </li>" +
         "   <li> <a onClick='multiPlay()'> Multiplayer </a> </li>" +
         "</ul> ";
};
```

Comment: Yes, I have an element with `id="log"`. 
Here is a fiddle with all of my files http://jsfiddle.net/gateway12231/w8z4skyt/

Comment: you have a lot of issues with your code. I've fixed a few, but your main problem in the fiddle was that **1)** your script needed to load in the `<head>` tag because elements required the script to be in place, **2)** You were missing a curly brace at [current] line 93 **3)** order of variable assignments matters, and **4)** added many missing semicolons.  I didn't look through too much of the code, but my changes fixed at least 4 errors so far.  http://jsfiddle.net/w8z4skyt/3/

Comment: This may not be the place for you to explain it to me, but I am fairly new to Stack Overflow and Web Dev/programming also. What do you mean by the script needed to load in the `<head>` tag? Also could you explain "order of variable assignment"? @ps2goat

Comment: in jsfiddle, you can choose when the javascript code should execute. It's the second dropdown on the left side of the page.  choosing `no wrap -- in <head>` means your script will be defined in the `<head>` tag of the html page, and thus available to all elements while the html is loading.

Comment: "Order of variable assignment" means the order that you have defined your variables and then assigned values to them.  For example, you had some code that was trying to use the variable `playerNum`, but `playerNum` was not declared nor given a value until later in the script block.  Variables must be declared before you try to use them.  If values are expected to be in those variables, then assignments must be made to those variables.  E.g., `var playerNum;` defines a variable.  `playerNum = 4;` is an assignment of the number `4` to `playerNum`.  `var playerNum = 4;` does both at once.

Comment: Okay, makes more sense now, but I was using Notepad ++ to make this. Is there a way to do the no wrap thing with out jsfiddle? @ps2goat

Comment: Just put the script in the `<head>` element:  `<html><head><title></title><script type="text/javascript">function x(){} </script></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Or put the JS in a separate file and link to it.